# Provision several files located on folder

Tags: chef-infra

I need to provision several files located under a directory on another directory of the provisioned machine.

So, I need some files on my chef repository located under `files/scripts/*.painless` are located on a folder (`#{es_config_r.path_conf}/scripts/`) of the provisiong machine.

Is there any way to do that, or I need to provision one by one?

I don't if I've explained so well...

Comment: You mean those files from below the cookbooks `files/` folder?

Comment: I want to provision all `files/scripts/` files to `#{es_config_r.path_conf}/scripts/`.

Comment: And is that folder located on the node that you're provisioning (because you download and unzipped ES/Kibana before) or is this in your cookbook?

Answer (score 2):

To place all files from within the `files/` folder from your cookbook, you can use the [`remote_directory`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_remote_directory.html) resource as follows:

```rb
remote_directory "#{es_config_r.path_conf}/scripts/"
```

should already do the job, given you're using the folder name `scripts/` on both sides.

To make the example a bit more clearer, you could place the painless scripts in `files/scripts/painless/`. This folder's contents can be provisioned as follows:

```rb
remote_directory "#{es_config_r.path_conf}/scripts/" do
  source "scripts/painless"
end
```

Comment: For this task I believe that using the [cookbook_file](https://docs.chef.io/resource_cookbook_file.html) resource is a more appropriate approach than remote_file. As it says in the documentation: `Use the cookbook_file resource to transfer files from a sub-directory of COOKBOOK_NAME/files/ to a specified path located on a host that is running the chef-client.`

Comment: Same holds for `remote_folder`, despite I find the chosen name a bit confusing (`remote_folder` doesn't work like `remote_file)`. The docs say here: `Use the remote_directory resource to incrementally transfer a directory from a cookbook to a node. The directory that is copied from the cookbook should be located under COOKBOOK_NAME/files/default/REMOTE_DIRECTORY.`

Answer (score -1):

You can deploy files contained within a cookbook using the resource [cookbook_file](https://docs.chef.io/resource_cookbook_file.html).

With a simple loop, you can deploy all the files in that directory, something like:

```
%w(foo bar zaz).each do |script|
  cookbook_file "/path/to/#{script}" do
    source "scripts/#{script}"
    owner 'MrBean'
    group 'ITV'
    mode '0754'
  end
end
```

Assuming for this, of course, that you have your scripts in your cookbook under directory `your_cookbook/files/scripts/`.

Other more elegant option is keeping the list of script files as an attribute for your cookbook, so you can deploy dinamically scripts on a *per machine* basis. (For exmample, not keeping scripts related to manage httpd server in the mysql one)

Comment: Would have done this before `remote_directory` became available.

Comment: By doing this you have more control on which files are deployed on what machine, without having redundant copies of the same scripts in different directories.